# Place Complete order in prestashop using webservice

Tags: php, android, web-services, prestashop

I am trying to add an order in prestashop through webservices. But my order is getting payment error every time. The problem is my discount and shipping is not reflecting in the order panel in admin dashboard.

Here is my code:

```
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);


$customer = array();
$product = array();


$id['country'] = '165';
$id['lang'] = $raw_data['id_lang'];
$id['currency'] = $raw_data['id_currency'];
$id['carrier'] = $raw_data['id_carrier'];

$product['order_rows'] = $raw_data['order_rows'];
//            $product['id'] = $id_product;
//            $product['price'] = Product::getPriceStatic($product['id']);
//            $product['name'] = Product::getProductName($product['id']);
//$product['total'] = $product['price'] * $product['quantity'];

$customerid = $raw_data['id_customer'];
// ID of created customer

$id['customer'] = $customerid;

// CREATE Address

$addresid = $raw_data['id_address_delivery'];
// ID of created address

$id['address'] = $addresid;

// CREATE Cart
$cartid = $raw_data['id_cart'];
// ID of created cart

$id['cart'] = $cartid;





//$sql = "select  id_order from ps_orders order by id_order desc limit 0,1";
//$r = mysql_query($sql, $conn)or die(mysql_error($conn));
//$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
//// CREATE Order
//$id['order'] = $row['id_order'] + 1;


$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/orders?schema=blank'));

$xml->order->id_customer = $id['customer'];
$xml->order->id_address_delivery = $id['address'];
$xml->order->id_address_invoice = $id['address'];
$xml->order->id_cart = $id['cart'];
$xml->order->id_currency = $id['currency'];
$xml->order->id_lang = $id['lang'];
$xml->order->id_carrier = $id['carrier'];
$xml->order->current_state = "3";
$xml->order->valid = 0;

$xml->order->total_shipping = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];

$xml->order->total_discounts = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->payment = 'Cash on delivery';
$xml->order->module = 'cashondelivery';
$xml->order->total_products = $raw_data['total_products'];
$xml->order->total_products_wt = $raw_data['total_products'];
$xml->order->total_paid = "0";
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_incl = "0";
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_excl ="0";
$xml->order->total_paid_real = "0";



$xml->order->conversion_rate = '1';

//            foreach ($products as $product){
//            $xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row->product_id = $product['id'];
//            $xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row->product_quantity = $product['quantity'];
//            }

$opt = array('resource' => 'orders');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
 $xml = $webService->add($opt);
//$xml=$webService->parseXML($xml);
$id['order'] = $xml->order->id;
//var_dump($xml->order);

$id['secure_key'] = $xml->order->secure_key;
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/order_carriers?schema=blank'));

$xml->order_carrier->id_carrier = $id['carrier'];
$xml->order_carrier->id_order = $id['order'];
$xml->order_carrier->shipping_cost_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order_carrier->shipping_cost_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$opt = array('resource' => 'order_carriers');

$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add($opt);


foreach ($raw_data['discounts'] as $discount) {
    $xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/order_discounts?schema=blank'));

    $xml->order_cart_rule->id_cart_rule = $discount['id_cart_rule'];
    $xml->order_cart_rule->id_order = $id['order'];
    $xml->order_cart_rule->value = $discount['value'];
    $xml->order_cart_rule->name = $discount['name'];
    $xml->order_cart_rule->value_tax_excl = $discount['value'];

    $opt = array('resource' => 'order_discounts');

    $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
    $xml = $webService->add($opt);
}
$sql = "update ps_order_history set id_order_state=3 where id_order=" . $id['order'];
$r = mysql_query($sql, $conn)or die(mysql_error($conn));

$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/orders/'.$id['order']));

$xml->order->id_customer = $id['customer'];
$xml->order->id_address_delivery = $id['address'];
$xml->order->id_address_invoice = $id['address'];
$xml->order->id_cart = $id['cart'];
$xml->order->id_currency = $id['currency'];
$xml->order->id_lang = $id['lang'];
$xml->order->id_carrier = $id['carrier'];
$xml->order->current_state = "3";
$xml->order->valid = 0;

$xml->order->total_shipping = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];

$xml->order->total_discounts = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->payment = 'Cash on delivery';
$xml->order->module = 'cashondelivery';
$xml->order->total_products = $raw_data['total_products'];
$xml->order->total_products_wt = $raw_data['total_products'];
$xml->order->total_paid = $raw_data['total_paid'];
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_paid'];
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_excl =$raw_data['total_paid'];
$xml->order->total_paid_real = "0";



$xml->order->conversion_rate = '1';



$opt = array('resource' => 'orders',"id"=>$id['order']);
$opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->edit($opt);
$id['orderrefer'] = $xml->order->reference;
```

[image: The problem is with admin dashboard. Coupons and shipping is not getting applied. so it is changing my payment status to payment error]

Comment: Can you post the error/errors? Which version of prestashop are you using?

Comment: hello sarcom, I am not getting any errors. Problem is with the admin dashboard. if i use any discount and shipping charges it says payment error. I  added an screenshot of admin dashboard. and my prestashop version is 1.6.0.14

Comment: You have to do the right calculations with shipping, discounts, etc, when you do an order through webservices, because when you place an order from the web, it's prestashop that do this calculus for us, but through webservices if you give a wrong digit you'll get into that error.

Comment: all the calculation are right it always changes the status to payment error and removes disciujt and shipping charges from my order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For placing order through webservice you need to make some entries directly to db with respect to cart like delivery option in cart table and for discount add entries in ps_cart_cart_rule table then place and order as you were placing.

```
foreach ($raw_data['discounts'] as $discount) {
foreach ($raw_data['discounts'] as $discount) {
    $sql = "insert into ps_cart_cart_rule values('" . $id['cart'] . "','" . $discount['id_cart_rule'] . "')";
    $r = mysql_query($sql, $conn)or die(mysql_error($conn));
}

$sql = "update ps_cart set `delivery_option`='a:1:{i:" . $id['address'] . ";s:3:\"" . $id['carrier'] . ",\";}', `id_carrier`='" . $id['carrier'] . "' where id_cart='" . $id['cart'] . "'";
$r = mysql_query($sql, $conn)or die(mysql_error($conn));


$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/orders?schema=blank'));

$xml->order->id_customer = $id['customer'];
$xml->order->id_address_delivery = $id['address'];
$xml->order->id_address_invoice = $id['address'];
$xml->order->id_cart = $id['cart'];
$xml->order->id_currency = $id['currency'];
$xml->order->id_lang = $id['lang'];
$xml->order->id_carrier = $id['carrier'];
$xml->order->current_state = "3";
$xml->order->valid = 0;
$xml->order->total_shipping = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_shipping'];
$xml->order->total_discounts = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_discounts'];
$xml->order->payment = 'Cash on delivery';
$xml->order->module = 'cashondelivery';
$xml->order->total_products = $raw_data['total_products'];
$xml->order->total_products_wt = $raw_data['total_products'];
$xml->order->total_paid = $raw_data['total_paid'];
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_incl = $raw_data['total_paid'];
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_excl = $raw_data['total_paid'];
$xml->order->total_paid_real = "0";
$xml->order->conversion_rate = '1';
$opt = array('resource' => 'orders');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add($opt);
$id['order'] = $xml->order->id;
$id['secure_key'] = $xml->order->secure_key;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem by direct entries to db tables for shipping and discounts.